# Can you use Assassinate on Multiple Targets

Tags: dnd-5e

Is Assassinate's surprise clause only limited to one target? In other words, I can't surprise a group with effects requiring a saving throw such as Subtle Spell Fireball, plant a Bomb under a table before a mafia get together, or my personal favorite Delayed Blast Fireball?

Comment: I edited this a little bit to make it read better. Please make sure I've not altered your question's intent. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> **Assassinate**
>
> Starting at 3rd level, you are at your deadliest when you 
>   get the drop on your enemies. You have advantage on 
>   attack rolls against any creature that hasn’t taken a turn 
>   in the combat yet. In addition, any hit you score against 
>   a creature that is surprised is a critical hit.

Assassinate **only** applies to **attack rolls**. If you can make more than one attack you can assassinate more than one creature (or the same creature multiple times). Ways of getting more than one attack include two weapon fighting, multiclassing to a class that gets extra attack, being hasted, multiclassing to a sorcerer for twinned and or quickened spell etc.

Fireballs **do not** have attack rolls, they have saving throws and so don't work. Mechanics for bombs are up to your DM and would probably be area of effect saving throws- even if your bomb makes attacks it would be the bomb making them, not the assassin.

The prerequisites of Assassinate and Sneak Attack are *different*: you can qualify for none, either or both. A *good* assassin should always be trying for both. For completeness, the requirements of sneak attack are:

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with
>   an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.
>
> You don’t need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy 
>   isn’t incapacitated, and you don’t have disadvantage on
>   the attack roll.

So, **at the start of the combat**:

1. Determine surprise
2. Roll initiative - the assassin can only assassinate people who have not yet had their turn so winning this is crucial.
3. Make as many assassinations as you can on creatures that have not yet acted - this must be a weapon, spell or unarmed *attack* i.e. one where you roll to hit against an AC. These attacks are made with advantage.
4. If the creature is also surprised, *any* hit is a critical hit (of course, any roll of 20 is a critical hit irrespective of surprise).
5. If you are using a finesse or ranged *weapon* (i.e. not a spell or unarmed attack), you get sneak attack damage. Any critical hits double this along with the weapon dice.

Comment: A bomb or grenade might considered a weapon, and thus classed as a weapon attack.  See DMG p 267-268.  However, as written for that optional rule, the Dex save argues for more of a "spell like attack" than a weapon attack.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast spell attacks can get assassinate effects, they just can't get sneak attack. In an effect gives a saving throw it is not an attack.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that spells with saving throws cannot have critical hits, to emphasize why the second part of the ability does not work.

Comment: @ KorvinStarmast: Why are spells that have saves not susceptible to criticals, is it because of the "there's no attack roll" thing? Where can find thi s in PHB and DMG. So does this mean as assassin caster can't use fire ball on a surprised small crowd and deal crit damage to said crowd ?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver it's in the definition of critical hit in the PHB - a critical requires a 20 on the attack roll, spells with saves (like fireball) do not have an attack roll

Comment: So let me get this as simplified as I can can with using Assassinate with spells.  1: Cant Sneak Attack cause spell and SA damage both scale with level and spell slot level so broken. 2:  Can have advantage on spells with Assassinate that has an attacks roll.  3: Can critical hit with spells that has an attack roll but does not have a saving throw so long as target/s is surprised. That about simple as I can put it together.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Yes, provided that you act *before* the person you want to assassinate - I will expand my answer.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver A spell with a Save is treated as always flying towards the intended point of aim, and you can't directly miss with it. The Save represents the target jumping out of the way (Dexterity), brushing it off (Constitution/Strength), recognizing and exploiting a flaw in the attack (Intelligence), or willing themselves through it (Charisma/Wisdom).

Comment: @DaleM For the purpose of clarity, how would you treat an arrow enchanted to be explosive, or an arrow with a lightweight explosive attached? It would have to be aimed to hit like a normal arrow, but it would explode on impact.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath what non-homebrew thing allows this?

Comment: @DaleM Say you cast Glyph of Warding on a singular arrow, specified it to Explosive and which operated when someone touched the arrow, and fired it at a target?
  Alternatively, improvising an arrow with a bottle of Alchemist's Fire attached to the head of the arrow instead of a traditional tip?

Comment: @SeraphsWrath Good questions: ask them.