# Mystic's Ethereal Weapon Discipline from Unearthed Arcana and Sneak Attack/Assassinate

Tags: dnd-5e, sneak-attack, unearthed-arcana

Do Mystic's Disciplines function like Spells for the purpose of Sneak Attack and and Assassinate ability? Cause the stipulation is, *"The next attack you make with it before the end of your turn ignores the target’s armor, requiring no attack roll"* meaning there is a weapon attack action so can I apply SA?

> Ethereal Weapon (1 psi): As a bonus action, you temporarily transform
> one weapon you’re holding or your unarmed strike into pure psionic
> energy. The next attack you make with it before the end of your turn
> ignores the target’s armor, requiring no attack roll. Instead, the
> target makes a Dexterity saving throw against this discipline. On a
> failed save, the target takes the attack’s normal damage and suffers
> its additional effects. On a successful save, the target takes half
> damage from the attack but suffers no additional effects that would
> normally be imposed on a hit.
>
> — [*Unearthed Arcana: The Mystic Class*](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

Just like in [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97174/15469), whether it's a spell or not has nothing to do with whether these features work. What matters is that you make an attack. Sneak Attack requires you to use a weapon for the attack:

> Once
>   per
>   turn,
>   you
>   can
>   deal
>   an
>   extra
>   1d6
>   damage
>   to
>   one
>   creature
>   you
>   hit
>   with
>   an
>   attack
>   if
>   you
>   have
>   advantage
>   on
>   the
>   attack
>   roll.
>   The
>   attack
>   must
>   use
>   a
>   finesse
>   or
>   a
>   ranged
>   weapon.

While Assassinate just requires an attack:

> In addition, any hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a critical hit.

But with Ethereal Weapon, you're not making an attack. You're forcing the target to make a saving throw. The PHB includes a very straightforward statement for questions like this:

> If
>   there’s
>   ever
>   any
>   question
>   whether
>   something
>   you’re
>   doing
>   counts
>   as
>   an
>   attack,
>   the
>   rule
>   is
>   simple:
>   if
>   you’re
>   making
>   an
>   attack
>   roll,
>   you’re
>   making
>   an
>   attack.

Therefore, regardless of the fact that you're using a weapon, you aren't making an attack, and these abilities cannot trigger.

Comment: *You aren't making an attack with a weapon* would be more clear/precise in your last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Qualification: Unearthed Arcana is playtest material, [there will be bugs and weirdness as it interacts with established rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/97579/23064). To stick with the spirit of playtesting, I am inclined to allow the sneak attack and see how it affects the game's balance. If it proves problematic, take it away.

The Action to use your Ethereal Weapon is not a separate Action, it is still an Attack Action:

> The next attack you make with it before the end of your turn ignores the target’s armor, requiring no attack roll.

Note that it doesn't say *"you can use an Action to make the target do a Dexterity Saving Throw..."*, instead, the wording is similar to that of Ensnaring Strike and the Paladin's many many smite spells, in that the power is held until you actually hit (but in this case, attack). The distinction is important because the former disallows you using the Multiattack feature, as you aren't making an Attack Action.

What this means for you is that you are still making an attack, possibly triggering Sneak Attack, but no longer need to make an attack roll. On a failure, you deal full damage with sneak attack; on a success, you deal half damage without sneak attack.

In my opinion, this is not overpowered. You're spending a resource (psi), and giving up any potential Advantages and other Bonuses from the attack (e.g. you do not benefit from Guiding Bolt, cannot use Bardic Inspiration, cannot flank). And it is much harder to impose penalties on enemy saving throws than it is to boost your attack roll.

Comment: @ daze413

"And it is much harder to impose penalties on enemy saving throws than it is to boost your attack roll."

What about the effect of a Hex spell?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Hex doesn't affect saving throws. Read the description carefully, it's tricky to spot the intricate details, but it's a handy skill to pick up for life, in general